# We have a 30in wide single door closet that we want to convert to sliding 60in closet, there is plenty of space to do this but how?

Tags: walls, framing, closet

We have a closet that has a single 30in hinged door that we want to open up and install a 60in wide sliding 2 panel door.  We have plenty of width and depth to remove the old door and open the wall to accommodate but how do I go about framing in the new open for the wider door frame?

Comment: Hire a building contractor who understands this stuff??

Comment: Frame it just like it is currently framed, but wider.